# Finding a percentage at a aggregate level from variables in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to SSRS.  I am trying to build a report which has a percentage calculation from 2 variables.  What happens is that it calculates percentages at the lowest level and adds them at highest level, so I am getting a percentage more than 100

Is there any way this percentage can be done at an aggregated higher level?

Sample data:

```
Dept  Store item  SOH  Range_count ( variable 1 )  OOS_count ( Variable 2 )       OOS_PERC ( Var 3 )
A     X     i1    10   1 ( ALWAYS 1)               0  ( IF soh <=0 ,1,ELSE 0)     0 ( var2/var1 )
A     X     I2    0    1                           1                              1 
A     X     I3    0    1                           1                              1
```

At the summary level I get the following data:

```
Dept  Range_count OOS_Count OOS_Perc
A     3           2         2  ( I am expecting 2 / 3 )
```

How do I achieve this in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression will be:

```
=Sum(Fields!OOS_Count.Value) / Sum(Fields!Range_Count.Value)
```

`Sum` will aggregate at the scope level, which in your department group footer is per department. You can put the same formula in your table footer and it will operate over the scope of the table - that is, for all data reported.